# How can I set pixel data storage for BITMAP

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, hbitmap

I have a following problem.
Somewhere I have defined array for storing pixels of my bitmap.

```
unsigned int table[512*512];
```

I would like this array to be used as data. I've found CreateBitmap(), but it does not behave in desired way. Instead of bounding the pointer to my table it creates a kind of snapshot of my array.

```
CreateBitmap(512, 512, 32, 1, table);
```

It looks like this:

```
table[5000]=0x00FFFFFF;
PlaceWhereICreateBitmap();
table[5001]=0x00FFFFFF;
PlaceWhereIDisplayBitmap(); //only pixel no. 5000 is updated
```

I want to display both changes.
I've also been reading about SetDIBits, but it copies array to the bitmap object. How can I set bitmap's buffer directly?

Comment: From what I can see, you are creating a pixel map with 32 planes and 1 bit for color.  I'm going to assume Windows will treat `table` as 262144 bits.  Color codes being 0 or 1 for each pel (1 bit each) across 32 planes.  Try changing the Planes to 1 and the color bits per pixel to 32.  So, `CreateBitMap(512, 512, 1, 32, table)` and see if later code makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, the arguments were passed in wrong order, thank you :) Unfortunately, it still does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **BitBlt** bit-block transfer function.

```
BitBlt(hDC, xDest, yDest, Width, Height, hMemDC, xSRC, ySRC, SRCCOPY);
```

Google the page, there is a lot more than just **SRCCOPY**.